# Default Scope of XPages Data Sources (xp:dominoDocument and xp:dominoView)

Tags: xpages

What is the default scope of `xp:dominoDocument` data source?

Sven Hasselbach posted an answer to another question, where he says that you have to set the scope of the data source to `request` scope and **his answer solves the problem**: 
[How can I refresh the XPages File Download Control and have it display updated attachments without full page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664774/how-can-i-refresh-the-xpages-file-download-control-and-have-it-display-updated-a)

My experience with the default scope of the `xp:dominoDocument` data source is, that the default scope is the `request` scope. I am working with managed beans and managed properties. When I inject a `xp:dominoDocument` data source as a managed property in a managed bean then I have to set the scope of this managed bean to `request` scope.

Otherwise (e.g. managed bean scope is set to `view`) I get the following error:

> 27.05.2015 13:04:55   HTTP JVM: Managedbean fileUploadHandler could not be created The scope of the referenced object:
>   '#{currentDocument}' is shorter than the referring object. For more
>   detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in
>   d:/Lotus/Domino/d

Comment: Is there a reason you're using dominoDocument with the managed bean? In my experience I usually use beans to REPLACE the need to use documents completely.  Just curious.  Thanks

Comment: @David: Thanks for your answer, I am also using beans in your way. 
With the bean example I wanted to show that the default scope is the request scope. For me in this case the interesting point is, why we have a different behaviour (see link above to the question and the following answer from Sven Hasselbach) of xp:dominoDocument data source when we set the scope explicit to request if obviously the default scope of the data source is the request scope (see Paul Stephen Withers answer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data source object will always sit in the request scope. What you are changing is the behaviour of the data container of the datasource, which is in the view scope by default.

When using the Debug Toolbar, you can see the behaviour: Even if you set the data source's scope to application scope, you still find the data source in the request scope. But also you will find a *DominoDocumentDataContainer* instance in the application scope.

If you are set the scope to *request*, the data container is also in the request scope. That's why the "file upload trick" works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand. Do you know some side effects (performance, etc.) of your "file upload trick"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, dominoDocument and dominoView are scoped to request, as Mark Leusink's Debug Toolbar from OpenNTF confirms.
[image: Debug Toolbar]

If you want to use a datasource, it may be easier to avoid using a managed property. You can still add the datasource to the page, but access it via `ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable(ExtLibUtil.getXspContext().getFacesContext(), "document1");` or navigate down to it from its container. Alternatively, you may be able to use managed properties for the document UNID, form etc, and instantiate a `com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData` in the bean's constructor or after a check for null in the getter.