# How to do a partial execution in an XPages multi-file upload

Tags: xmlhttprequest, xpages

I wrote some code based on the [work of Sven Hasselbach](http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1286). Files can be uploaded, but processing takes a lot of time. We noticed that, after each file is uploaded, a full page is returned and the full component tree is "executed". The sending of the full page can be suppressed by adding the line `frm.append( "$$ajaxid", "@none");` but is there also a way to reduce execution on the server?

I tried with

```
    frm.append( "execMode", "partial");
    frm.append( "execId", "#{id:fileUpload2}");
```

and also with $$ as prefixes to the names, to no avail so it seems. I still have to do further tests.

Any tips as to how to reduce server-side execution when doing a multi-file upload?

Thanks!

UPDATE: CSJS code that sends individual files

```
    var frm = new FormData();
    frm.append( "#{id:fileUpload2}", file);
    frm.append( "$$viewid", dojo.byId('view:_id1__VUID').value);
    frm.append( "$$ajaxid", "@none");
    frm.append( "$$execmode", "partial");
    frm.append( "$$execid", "#{id:fileUpload2}");
    //frm.append( "$$xspsubmitid", "#{id:saveDoc}");
    frm.append( "view:_id1", "view:_id1");

    xhr.open("POST", "#{javascript:facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURI()}", true);
    xhr.send(frm);
```

Comment: What is the performance time for each phase, plus also performance time from browser to server and vice versa? There are various examples of PhaseListener code on XSnippets.I'd recommend doing some benchmarks. Then, do the benchmark timings alter if you upload fewer or more attachments? If they change, it's the size of the attachments that's the problem - they are streamed as bytes from the browser, converted to full attachments, and persisted to the server. If they don't and all phases take a long time, it may be time to look at persistence settings and also where the files are persisted.

Comment: If the performance issue is the time converting and saving the attachments to disk, that's the area to investigate potential alternatives. There may be relevant information in "Mastering XPages Second Edition" or "XPages Portabl Command Guide". Reducing server-side execution with e.g. execMode won't help and could cause more problems, like lost data on the browser.

Comment: Hi Paul, we do a lot of logging in our application. Each afterRenderResponse is logged, and each afterRestoreView event as well. They are there, per file, and all XPages goes through all phases. Nothing else changes on the document or page. The automatic save is also disabled. we have some forms displayed, and all form fields are re-evaluated, for no good reason actually.

Comment: The real issue is in fact that the HTML5 <input type=file multiple> isn't supported in XPages, for then the component thee would be processed only once.

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers Would [Sven's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664774/how-can-i-refresh-the-xpages-file-download-control-and-have-it-display-updated-a/18697148#18697148) still apply? It sounded like the POSTing of the file only occurs with a Full refresh, not with partial. I know it's something I've run into _previously_, but I haven't tried a partial refresh w/ `xp:fileUpload` in a long time.

Comment: Hm, I don't think so. I don't even do a partial refresh of the screen to display the files. I'll add the current JS code to the question text.

Comment: It's passing the file to an AJAX request (even though nothing is posted back to the browser, it's still the partial refresh process that runs), calling the `saveDoc` eventHandler. That eventHandler would be the one on which the settings for the server-processing need to be - same as in a normal partial refresh. So that's where you would set execMode and execId (it would probably need to include the document1 datasource). That should restrict the processing.

Comment: Hm. I deactivated the eventHandler on `saveDoc`. I'll see what happens if I do some tinkering with it. Thanks.

Comment: It still processes the page after every file upload, but I think phases 4 (Update Model) and 5 (Invoke Application) are now skipped, so it goes from Process Validations directly to Before Render Response. More testing required! 'tWould be nice to have a proper multi-file upload in XPages. The funny thing is that the calls seem to support it: in the com.ibm.xsp.http.UploadedFile class, there are both getClientFileName() and getClientFileNames(), as well as getServerFile() and getServerFiles()...